# Posts with no meta field do not appear when sorting by meta field

Tags: post-meta, sort

I want to order my posts by a custom meta field "fieldA". I am using the following code:

```
$query->set( 'meta_key', 'fieldA);
$query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
$query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
```

Ordering works fine but there is a problem. All posts which do not have the meta_key "fieldA" are not fetched. Any idea what's wrong? thx

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you specify 'meta_key' without a 'meta_value' it checks merely for the existence of the meta_key. I haven't tried this but you might be able to specify a 'meta_compare' of '!=' and some random value for 'meta_value' that you know would never actually be set as the value.

```
$query->set( 'meta_key', 'fieldA' );
$query->set( 'meta_value', 'okeedokeedoggiedaddie' );
$query->set( 'meta_compare', '!=' );
$query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
$query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
```

Comment: thx for the reply but unfortunately it does not do the trick :( .. isn't possible to force LEFT JOIN with the postmeta tablet instead of the INNER JOIN?

Comment: anyone have an idea? I am reluctant in modifying the core meta query class directly